# Preselecting an option from a select field in a fields array?

Tags: php, forms, select, laravel-5

Observe the following $fields array, which is used as an input form in a blade:

```
$fields = [
    'user_id'           => [
        'label' => 'Opportunity Owner' . $req,
        'type'  => 'select',
        'class' => 'select2',
        'opts'  => User::whereTenantId(tenant()->id)->whereRole('Admin')->get()->lists('name', 'id')->all()
    ],
    'name'              => [
        'label' => 'Opportunity Name' . $req,
    ],
    'agent_id'          => [
        'label'       => 'Agent',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'class'       => 'select2',
        'textAsValue' => false,
        'opts'        => array_replace([0 => '-- Select Sales Rep --'],
                         User::whereTenantId(tenant()->id)->whereRole('Admin')->get()->lists('name', 'id')->all()),
    ],
    'description'       => [
        'label' => 'Description',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'submit',
        'label' => 'Save',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary !important'
    ]

];
```

In the 'agent_id' part, I'd like to pre-select a value if the user has a value preassigned. I know how to get the info from the user, but I am lost as to how to 'select' an option in the array within the 'agent_id' field. I need all options to show in the select, but I want to be able to have one 'selected' based on the agent_id number linked to the user. I tried the following:

```
'agent_id'          => [
        'label'       => 'Agent',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'class'       => 'select2',
        'textAsValue' => false,
        'opts'        => array_replace([0 => '-- Select Sales Rep --'],
                         User::whereTenantId(tenant()->id)->whereRole('Admin')->get()->lists('name', 'id')->all()),
        'selected' => {{appropriate number here}}

    ],
```

But that did not work. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Add selected value without any index.
Try this:

```
'agent_id'          => [
        'label'       => 'Agent',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'class'       => 'select2',
        'textAsValue' => false,
        'opts'        => array_replace([0 => '-- Select Sales Rep --'],
                         User::whereTenantId(tenant()->id)->whereRole('Admin')->get()->lists('name', 'id')->all()),
        {{appropriate number here}}

    ],
```